# How to fix error which appears on my batch code (filter program)?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run a batch program to filter users email and password which is in the format of email:password and also with lot of unwanted words and same other this symbols ":" in the text file.

This is to filter my users details using batch program

`@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('FindStr /L ":" "file.txt"')Do @Echo(%%~nxA>>"combo.txt"` This is the code am using. `file.txt` contains those `email:pass` and other texts too. `combo.txt` is output with filtered email:pass

file.txt contains,

```
Username: emailaddress@mail.com
Password: password123
As Combo: emailaddress@mail.com:password123
Subscription: Premium
Recurring date: 7/8/19
Status: Premium for Family
Country: DE
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT in `combo.txt` is,

```
emailaddress@mail.com:password123
```

BUT I GOT ACTUAL OUTPUT in `combo.txt` is,

```
Username: emailaddress@mail.com
Password: password123
As Combo: emailaddress@mail.com:password123
Subscription: Premium
19
Status: Premium for Family
Country: DE
```

Comment: You must put spaces in front of redirection operators if what appears before it contains or may contain numbers. If processing `password123` the 3 will become the file handle you are redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

life is much easier when you filter your data down to what you really need:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('type file.txt^|find "As Combo:"') do >combo.txt echo %%a
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided there is only one set of `Username:` and `Password:` in `File.txt` :

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\06\09\SO_56516697.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal
Set "Username="
Set "Password="
for /f "tokens=1*delims=: " %%A in ('
    findstr /i "^Username: ^Password:" "File.txt" 
') Do Set "%%A=%%B"
If defined Username if defined Password (
  Echo:%Username%:%Password%
)>>"combo.txt"
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\06\09\SO_56516697.cmd

> type combo.txt
emailaddress@mail.com:password123
```

Of course it is also possible to filter multiple sets of `Username:` and `Password:` with more processing inside a for (code block).

Comment: This works but, it concentrates on only Username and password. But, which i asked was for combo like email:pass . If there is no username and password, the code you provided is not gonna work

Comment: I think your question wasn't that unambiguous, otherwise I hadn't suggested  a more complex solution, than @Stephan's simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using your one-liner format,

```
For /F "tokens=1,2,*Delims=: " %%A In ('FindStr /L ":" "%filename1%"') Do IF "%%A%%B"=="AsCombo" Echo(%%C>"u:\combo.txt"
```

Noting that I've changed the filenames to suit my system.
The code uses both `:` and <kbd>Space</kbd> as delimiters. On the target line, `As` will be assigned the first token, `%%A` and `Combo` to `%%B` Hence "%%A%%B"=="AsCombo" will select the `As Combo` line and the value required will be assigned to `%%C` on that line.

Notice I reduced `>>` to `>` to `create anew` not `append`.

Actually, the `FindStr /L ":"` could be replaced by `type` as there's no real advantage to filtering for lines containing `:`.

Not having the space between the `)` and `DO` appears to work, but isn't standard.